# An animation problem in the vicinity of the boundary with an element at hover

Tags: css

I use the transform property for animation when I hover and set animation such as rotation to element.

However, this occasionally causes defects like the image below.

Regarding this problem, I confirm that no matter what site I look at it is not written.

And even Twitter to this problem does not correspond!

How should I respond to this problem?

[animation problem in the vicinity of the boundary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VVPx8.gif)

---

For example, suppose you have HTML with such a CSS applied.

```css
a {
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
  width: 150px;
  background: #a0f;
  border-radius: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  transition: all 0.6s ease;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px #50a
}

span {
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 50px;
}

#link:hover {
  border-radius: 25px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a id="link">
    <span>text</span>
  </a>
</div>
```

When hovering to the right boundary of this button, the button repeats expansion and contraction at short intervals.

A problem similar to this is occurring in the twitter gif uploaded above.
How should I fix this problem?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you help us out by adding some of your code or a live preview.

Comment: Let us see your code, this is interesting

Comment: Added example code. Thank you.

Comment: Your button changes widths when you hover it. If you hover over the right side, the button shrinks away from your mouse, and you're no longer hovering it. So it begins to expand back to it's "unhovered" state, until it hits your mouse cursor, at which point you're hovering it again. Repeat indefinitely. Generally not a great idea to have buttons change size and shape when hovered, not only because you run into side effects like this, but it's awful for UX and accessibility.

Comment: when your element gets hovered it shrinks, if hover from the right side, it'll shrink and run away from the mouse, now it's not hovered anymore, so goes back to it's normal width, but then it's hovered again, and it keeps repeating that, One fix is have a wrapper that doesn't shrink. This might be a fix to the problem, but it would be weird as a visual effect.

Comment: Tyler Roper> I think that's true. How should we resolve the problem that animation repeats when you mouse over such a boundary? I do not know the optimal solution.

Comment: Zohir Salak>Parent elements that do not stretch are certainly valid, but **they can also click on parts that should not be clickable.** I think that this is a bad problem than the problems being induced now.

Comment: There isn't really a "solution" because there isn't anything wrong - the button is doing exactly what you've told it to do. You'll have to clearly define what you want to happen when the button is hovered. As I mentioned above, the main issue here is having a button that runs away from your mouse when you hover it.

Comment: @euq29i No, you can control what's clickable, the wrapper is there just for the effect, **dimensions changes onhover are a bad practice from the start.**